# Jenkins Pipline - loop over array of nodes

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

The aim is to have a dynamic pipeline. I've several nodes with specific configurations. I would like to build my job on **all** of them, not reguarding the number of nodes and without copy&paste.

The code below would work  but it is throwing an [exception](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46480). Is there any known workaround out there to accomplish a dynamic pipeline? (declarative or like this example the scripted pipeline)

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
    ActiveNode=aSlave.getLabelString()
    node(ActiveNode){

    node(aSlave.getLabelString()) { //java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.libvirt.VirtualMachineLauncher

        stage(aSlave.name){
            echo 'Hello World'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the method returnin a non serializable object in a method annotated with @NonCPS.

*aSlave.getLabelString()* is not the culprit, but aSlave. A possible solution would be:

```
@NonCPS
def agentNames() {
  hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves.collect{[(it.labelString):(it.name)]}​
}

for (agent in agentNames()) {
  node(agent.keySet()[0]) {
    stage(agent.values()[0]){
      echo 'Hello World'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you've saved my day! thx!
So what is a `non serializable object` (*NSO*) and what does `@NonSPC`?
Is it like the .collect returns a NSO, @NonSPC is transforming it and the for-loop just accepts the result? Can you give me a link for future reading about this topic?

Comment: after some reading: is the .collect-method the one which is non interrupt able for be written on hdd? So the function is wrapping this part into a @NonCPS environment?

This function is returning a simpel key:value-array, which then can be used to trigger the nodes?

Comment: The @NonCPS annotation inhibits serialization attempts (plus other functionalities) . This way, a non-serializable object (instantiated from a class not implementing the [Serializable interface] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) ), won't cause an error.

Comment: thanks! Which class of them is not serializable?
hudson? model? instance? Is there a way to check if a class has the serializ-abilety?

Comment: The class is hudson.plugins.libvirt.VirtualMachineLauncher. Looking for it code or Javadoc will help into guessing if it is Serializable.

Comment: Please note that it is not save to call any pipeline functions like echo from within nonCPS. You may get an exception, something like CpsCallableInvication. First you need a NonCPS method to collect the node names into an array. This is to be called from the Methode without NonCPS and where the loop goes.